# How to test multiple key value pairs aka JSON

Tags: jestjs

I am attempting to set up a JEST test against JSON key:value pairs, however I am getting test failures.  Does anybody have experience in testing JSON key:value pairs?

File name CountryCodeMapping.js

```
export const ContryCodeMappingList = {
     "United States": "USA",
     "Argentina": "ARG,
     ...
```

Test File name CountryCodeMapping.test.js

```
import {CountryCodeMappingList 
} from "./CountryCodeMappingList.js";

describe("Constant to ensure no change are made that pass tests ", () => {
   test("are json key value pairs matching", () => {
      expect (CountryCodeMapppingList).toContain(
         "UnitesStates: USA",
         Argentina": ARG",
         ...
  );
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

To test the **key:value** pairs aka json object

```
import{ CountryCodeMappingList
} from "./CountryCodeMappingList.js";

test("are json key value pairs matching", () =>{
expect(CountryCodeMapppingList).toMatchObject({"Uniteds States": USA",
                                               "Agentina": "ARG",
                                               ...})
})
```